# OpenShift Online Outgoing Connections Permission Denied

Tags: ssl, imap, openshift, gmail-imap

I'm trying to port an Java/JBoss application running in EC2 to OpenShift and currently am using a free account.

The application uses Apache Camel and establishes outgoing imaps (port 993) connections to Gmail.  It has been working fine in EC2 but gets 'Permission Denied' errors when run in JBoss inside OpenShift

According to this
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/outbound-mail-ports-are-now-open-for-business-on-openshift
port 993 should be open for outgoing connections.

Is this a restriction because I'm using a free account?  Should I be able to establish outgoing imaps connections to Gmail?

Comment: Can you ssh into your gear and telnet to that port on that domain?